# IE8 vs IE9 Compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm required to test a website using IE 9 but I'm blocked when IE 9 can't be installed using Wine because Wine only supports Windows XP.  I resort to install IE 8. I'm going to run the website and hoping some layouts will not be distorted.

My question is will it be sufficient to test the website on IE 8? Will there be no problems when opening it on IE 9 upon the website deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient. Hosting a website means you need to check compatibility not only with IE, but also with all web kit browser versions.

You asked about IE8 vs IE9. These two are entirely different, so it's not enough to check the compatibility in IE8 alone.

If you want to do cross platform and IE version compatibility, there are a lot of online tools.

- [Cross Platform  Check](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/tools-browser-compatibility-check/)

Where 3rd section is downloadable, it will check the IE version compatibility check.

Comment: Thanks for the link of the tools! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not sufficient to only test a website on IE8.  IE8 is old and quite different from IE9 and IE10 in many ways.

Comment: Can you suggest any applications that can run IE 9 on ubuntu? @jfriend00

Comment: @Jhn - sorry I don't know ubuntu and what's available for it.

Comment: @Jhn The best way to test IE on Linux/MacOS is to use a virtual machine: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads + https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: That's right. I am working on an MVC 4 CRUD app that looks good in IE9, but we are having problems with scroll bars within a DIV not working - a crucial problem. MVC 4 projects default to use Modernizr which is supposed to fix problems like that.....so you really do have to check a site out on different browsers and you might also check with Compatibility View on, and off.

Answer (score 1):

You have to test the site on all browsers, or you can limit your site to be shown only on certain  browser where you are sure it will work fine.